# The range of arc-cotangent function & arccot(-1).

Tags: trigonometry

We know that the **range** of **arc-cotangent** function is **$(0,π)$**

and we I calculate the value of $cot^{-1}(-1)$ by a calculator, I get **($-π/4$)**

Which is clearly not included in the range !!

Why isn't it $(3π/4)$?

I am very confused !

Comment: You are right unlike the calculator

Comment: $3π/4$ is the correct answer and $-π/4$ is incorrect. right?

Comment: Yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Answer (score 1):

Conventions differ.  Apparently your calculator is not using the same definition of arc-cotangent as you are.

Comment: So, what should be the correct answer ?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer would be that your calculator has a different definition of arc-cotangent. It is not wrong to say that $-\pi / 4 $ is a solution of the equation $\cot (x) = -1$, and this is how your calculator understands it.

Nevertheless, there is a unique root of the equation $\cot (x) = -1$ lying in the (open) interval between $0$ and $\pi$. You will find it adding or substracting $\pi$ to any other solution an appopriate (integer) number of times (you can work out the actual number using the integer part function).

Hope this helps.

Comment: and what is the correct answer?

Comment: As I tried to explain, there is no *correct* answer. You only need to be consistend with yourself, and choose *a* definition of the arccotengent function.

Comment: ... or, if you are a student, use the definition your instructor uses.  But be aware that other people (or devices) may use a different definition.